# FactorInteger snippet works, but use of Sow/Reap/Print is clunky

Tags: number-theory, code-review

This is a code review or de-clunking request. If it doesn't belong here,
I'll withdraw it.

The below toy works and produces the proper output,
that is, for numbers to be factored that can be expressed as $a^b-1$, it
factors the factors of $a^x-1$, and in doing so renders some numbers factorable
in a reasonable time, by producing a list of numbers with exponents < x.

For
example, I stopped the still in-progress `FactorInteger[10^270-1]` after 2 weeks;
using below for $10^{270}-1$ takes about 5 seconds. So the issue is that the
`tbl = Reap ...`  section (and maybe more) looks like it could use improvement
that is currently beyond me.
Much obliged.

The `tbl=` section prints the symbolic factors of $h^{\rm mu}-1$, then prints for each the corresponding (numeric) factor of $10^{\rm mu}-1$. *Then* it tries to FactorInteger those numbers. At least, if it stalls, the problem number has already been printed. E.g., try $\rm mu=540$.

The `j=` section combs through the FactorInts (which are the 4th part of each tbl sublist),
grouping by prime factor and summing exponents, that is, reassembling into
FactorInteger format w/each prime factor appearing once.

The formula for Carmichael Lambda was lifted from
MathWorld: CarmichaelFunction.html

```
Clear[tbl, tblFI, b, k, mu, cm, cmL, cmLFI]
mu = 27;
k = Factor[h^mu-1];
b = 10;

Print[h^mu, "-1 = ", k]; Print[" "]

tbl = Reap[     
         Do[    
            {   
                 Print[Sow[k[[i]]]],
                 Print[Sow[k[[i]] /. h->b]],
                 Print[Sow[Apply[Times, Map[(Superscript[#[[1]], #[[2]]]) &, q=FactorInteger[k[[i]]/. h->b]]]];" "],
                 Sow[q]
             },
            {i, Length[k]}  
            ]
            ][[2]]  // Flatten[#, 1]&  // Partition[#, 4]&

Times @@(#[[1]]^#[[2]] & /@ Flatten[ tbl[[All, 4]], 1]) == b^mu-1  (* They'd better == *)  

j = (Total /@ SortBy[GroupBy[Flatten[tbl[[All, 4]], 1], First], First]) [[All, 2]] ; 
tblFI = Partition[Riffle[Keys[j], Values[j]], 2]   
     
cmL = LCM @@ (cm=Map[(#1[[1]]-1)#1[[1]]^(#1[[2]]-1)&, tblFI]); 
Print["cmL[", h^mu, "-1, h\[RightArrow]", b,"] = LCM @@ ", cm, "= ",  cmL]
cmLFI = FactorInteger[cmL]; 
Print[" = ", Apply[Times, Map[(Superscript[#[[1]], #[[2]]]) &, cmLFI]]]; 
Print[""]
Print["FI[", h^mu, "-1, h\[RightArrow]", b,"] = ", Apply[Times, 
Map[(Superscript[#[[1]], #[[2]]]) &, tblFI]]]
```

Comment: `CarmichaelLambda` has been in Mathematica since 11.3 (2013)

Comment: @flinty According to the document, `CarmichaelLambda` has been in Mathematica since 4.0 (1999)

Comment: @wuyudi indeed I stand corrected. It got an _update_ in 2013.

Comment: @flinty  But CarmichaelLambda is almost as expensive as FactorInteger, the point being that once you've labored to get FactorInteger, you can recycle that result into a roll-your-own Carmichael Lambda.